# qgis2web Leaflet - How to add the +/- symbol to reduce the layers in legend and how to add a logo in the webmap?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web

I'm newbie to edit HTML of Leaflet of qgis2web. I have some questions for you:

1. How can I put for each layer the sign "+" and "-" to reduce the legend of each layer.
2. How can I add a logo in the webmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant help with #1 but #2 see below.

You will want to create your own HTML template to use with qgis2web by copying the included full-screen.html file and adding the following code

```
<div id="map" style="z-index:1;">
<img src="http://demo.qgis.org/demos/alaska/alaska.png" alt="some_text" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:2;">
```

Obviously you will want to use you own image file.